# Serial - Parallel Process Equivalence

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Q: **Do Lorentz transformations give us an equivalence between serial and parallel processes, and if not, is there any literature on this line of thought?**

Naively,

1. Serial processes are connected sums of cylinders;
2. Parallel processes are connected sums of tori;
3. A torus and a cylinder are [Dupin cyclides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dupin_cyclide), and hence (unsure of this?) equivalent under a [Laguerre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_wave_transformation#Transformation_by_reciprocal_directions);
4. [There is an equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_wave_transformation#Laguerre_group_isomorphic_to_Lorentz_group) between Laguerre and Lorentz transformations.

Apologies in advance for incorrect tagging. My motivation is to relate a given parallel electrical circuit to a serial one with a Lorentz transformation. I'm also suspicious that this is a pretentious way of stating relativity of simultanaeity. Let me know if this is the case!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean when you claim that "serial processes are connected sums of cylinders" and "parallel processes are connected sums of tori"?

Comment: Yes, apologies, it's quite vague I'll admit, but if you picture the simplest possible serial circuit and cut one end (in a manner similar to how you go from a mathematical knot to a real-world knot) you'll have a cylinder - just picture a bunch of these connected together. If you consider the simplest possible parallel circuit (picture a battery one one end and two parallel semiconductors) and cut one end you'll end up with a torus, etc. Just want to spot where I'm fooling myself here.

Comment: Premises 1 and 2 are just two of the three cases of the classification theorem for compact surfaces, which states that any closed and connected surface is homeomorphic to either a) the sphere, b) a connected sum of tori, or c) a connected sum of projective planes. A cylinder is homeomorphic to the sphere, which covers the series circuits, and certainly many parallel circuits are homeomorphic to a connected sum of tori. But are _all_ parallel circuits this way? Can you demonstrate that no parallel circuits are homeomorphic to a connected sum of projective planes?

Comment: For example, I suspect that a circuit in the shape of the bipartite graph $K_{3,3}$, where each edge is a resistor, cannot be constructed as a connected sum of tori, based on the fact that this graph is planar on the Klein bottle (the connected sum of two projective planes).

Comment: Interesting - thanks for your replies. My first thought is that no circuit can be realised as a connected sum of projective planes because you can't smoothly embed these in $\mathbb{R}^3$, whereas a circuit is necessarily smoothly embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Any thoughts?

Comment: A smooth embedding might not be necessary. The Klein bottle can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ if you allow self-intersection, and it's not clear to me that self-intersection is a disqualifying condition.

Comment: Thank you - yes, I see the difficulty with this - although I would think that wires aren't usually passed through one another - this is nonetheless imaginable. I've parked this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652387/graph-embeddings-in-mathbbr3 if you're interested. I suppose we can restrict to the case where circuits aren't passed through one another for now (I'm not sure that this is very unreasonable, physically).